# jQuery: fade in/out + animate elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadein, fadeout

I'm using jQuery to fade in/out some elements and change the opacity of the others.

```
  $(function(){

        $('.image').each(function() {
            $(this).hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.3 }, 'slow');
                    $(this).siblings().fadeIn('slow');
                },

               function() {
                   $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 'slow');
                   $(this).siblings().fadeOut('slow');
               })
            });
        });
```

You can see the full code at http://projects.klavina.com/stackoverflow/01/ (I'm also using the jQuery Masonry plugin on the page).

I'm fairly new to JS/jQuery and the above code doesn't work well, unless I mousover the .image element really slowly. When I move over the elements faster, the captions over the images show even when I've already moved over another element. How can I remove that? I.e. the captions should fade in only when I'm still hovering that particular element.

The first image on the example site has a "z-index: 100;" for the caption, so I can get the text overlay at full opacity. Ideally, I would have "z-index: 100;" for all the captions, but this makes the hovering work even worse.

Plus, the fading in/out looks distorted in IE. How can I fix that? I did use the opacity change on another page, and fixed the IE bug by adding a white background to the element, but I can't do that here (as I have a photo underneath).

Thank you!

Comment: +1 for using Masonry - I've just found it and can't think of something cooler :-D As for your use of it, it looks great. Sorry I can't help you with your problem :-(

Comment: Isotope is cooler.  http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core cause of your issue is that you need a call to `.siblings().stop()`, *in addition* to the `$(this).stop()` (which you already have).

After you fix that, you'll see a new issue, where your captions initially work correctly, but then begin to fade in only partially once they've been moused-over repeatedly (and eventually, they'll disappear completely until you reload the page).  This is due to the way `.fadeIn()` works when combined with `.fadeOut()` -- `fadeIn()` doesn't always fade-in to `opacity:1` -- instead, it fades-in to whatever opacity was applied at the time `fadeOut()` was called previously.

To get around this, you can use `animate({opacity:1},'slow')` instead of `fadeIn('slow')` -- or you can use the more concise (and clearer) `.fadeTo('slow',1)` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)).  (note, the parameter order is different on fadeTo, as compared to the other animation functions - the duration comes first, then the value you want to fade to).

Of course, you could also use `fadeTo()` in place of your other opacity animation --though there is certainly nothing wrong with using `animate()` as you've shown -- the two are equivalent. (of course, you would need to se `animate()` if you want to manipulate multiple css properties at the same time.)

When it all comes together, it might look something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.image').each(function() {
        $(this).hover( function() {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow',0.3)
                .siblings().stop().fadeTo('slow',1);
        }, function() {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow',1)
                .siblings().stop().fadeTo('slow',0);
        });
    });
});
```

You can see this code in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/XstpE/

(note: that example depends on the hosted resources that go with the original post above, so it won't work if those get moved or become otherwise unavailable).

---

Also note: In the example above, I have included the use of `.each()` as you did in your original example, but I want to point out that it's really not necessary.

The following is equivalent (and would usually be considered "better" jQuery technique):

```
$(function() {
    $('.image').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.3)
            .siblings().stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1)
            .siblings().stop().fadeTo('slow', 0);
    });
});
```

When you apply an event handler to a multi-element set, jQuery automatically binds the same handler on every element in the set.  (I've updated my example at jsFiddle (linked above) to show the code *without* the `each()`).

---

**Edit**

The OP points out that hovering over the caption (which sits on top of the image) causes the `mouseleave` handler to trigger, thus resulting in the roll-out action being performed.  The desired behavior is to have the caption *not* trigger the rollout.

This issue happens because the caption "shadows" the image, and the `hover()` is applied to the image.  When the mouse rolls over the caption it's no longer on the image (it's on the caption) so the browser fires a mouseleave on the image.  This same situation can give rise to all sorts of other subtle problems too -- especially as you add more complex content.

To solve this, I recommend that you simply apply `hover()` one level up (to the container that holds the image *and* the caption), instead of applying it to the image directly.  In this case that container is `$('.entry')`.  The code would change like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.entry').hover(function() {
        $('.image',this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.3)
            .siblings().stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
    }, function() {
        $('.image',this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1)
            .siblings().stop().fadeTo('slow', 0);
    });
});
```

[here is a new version of the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/XstpE/7/)

Comment: Thank you for this and the explanation! Works perfectly in Safari/Chrome/Firefox. Unfortunately doesn't work so well in IE - http://projects.klavina.com/stackoverflow/01/index-02.html - when I mousover the <div class="caption"> area; the image fades in to opacity:1 & the caption text dissapears.

Comment: That happens because your `hover()` handler is on the image --not on the caption-- so when you roll over the caption, IE processes this as "leaving" the image.  The other browsers will do the same if you give your caption any of several positioning-related css attributes. There are other subtle issues that can crop up as a result of this too -- even Webkit & FF.  The best solution (in my opinion) is to put your `hover()` handler on `$('.entry')` instead of `$('.image')`.  [see updated jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/XstpE/7/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how long 'slow' paramater means in your animate functions. Try tweaking that to 'fast' or even provide a numeric value in milliseconds and see if that would help.

To stop animation on an element when your mouse leaves it:

```
$('.image').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).stop();
});
```

Comment: I need the animation to be that slow (slow = 600ms), so changing that to a faster value wouldn't help. I did try that anyway, but the problem is still there - the animation keeps happening on a previous layer, even when I've moved to another one. I believe I need to change the code in a way that it stops executing the animation when I'm off the element, but unfortunately I don't have the knowledge to do that.

Comment: If you want to try to stop animation on an element when your mouse leaves it, please see edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mouseenter() and mouseleave() instead of hover().

```
$(function(){
    $('.image').each(function() {
        $(this).mouseenter( function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.3 }, 'slow');
            $(this).siblings().fadeIn('slow');
        })
        .mouseleave( function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 'slow');
            $(this).siblings().fadeOut('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `hover()` binds `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` ([see docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)). Binding those events directly should make no difference at all.