# jQuery fade in problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, fadein

I'm trying to create a fade in effect using jQuery, html & CSS with no avail.  Basically, it's a navigation list with a gallery scroll effect using jQuery.. scrolling over contact link brings a popup with contact info and so on for services, about etc..

The gallery script I used can be found [here](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-image-swap-gallery/)

whenever I apply .fadein(slow), I get the desired affect but in reverse.  Instead of fading from transparent to opaque:::you get the  picture. I have also tried

```
.animate({opacity: '0.5'}, 1000)
```

with the same results as above

What my jOuery script looks like:

```
<script type>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Image swap on hover
    $("#gallery ul li img").hover(function(){
        $('#main-img').stop().fadeTo('slow',0.3).siblings()
          .stop().fadeTo('slow',1.0).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
    });
    // Image preload
    var imgSwap = [];
     $("#gallery ul li img").each(function(){
        imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
        imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
    });
    $(imgSwap).preload();
});
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}
</script>
```

The html:

```
<div id="left_nav">
    <div id="gallery">
     <img src="images/gallery/home.png" alt="" id="main-img" />
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/home.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li class="about"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/About Us.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li class="contact"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/Contact Us.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li class="services"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/Services.png" alt="" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

I have also tried reversing the opacity settings because it would seem like common sense. This results in an opaque affect only, no fade in.  What I'm shooting for is a fade in affect for hover state of thumbs.  Also, fade script doesn't seem to work in IE 8.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, some chaining going on here.  Why do you have to fade in the siblings as well (i.e. the ul tag) ?  Maybe you meant this?

```
$('#main-img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', '')).stop();
$('#main-img').hide();
$('#main-img').fadeIn();
```

It's deliberately unchained.  For some reason, chaining the hide and fadeIn calls together can make it stop working in some browsers, like IE.

Comment: You sir are the man, now my question is how to go about keeping the effect after scrolling through each link in the ul tag.  The affect seems to disappear after the first hover.

Comment: Found a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291154/jquery-fade-in-out-animate-elements

Comment: Yes I've had this happen on some browsers... IE *cough*.  Try unchaining it and separate it out into multiple statements.  I'll amend the answer.

Comment: Sorry, just joined yesterday so I'm unable to upvote although it was very helpful.  With this,stop() doesn't seem to stop the fade from repeating onmouseout, It's quite annoying how fadeTo() repeats once onmouse and then again onmouseout, I'm going for a seamless fade between links, any suggestions on how to stop the fade onmouseout?  Thanks for your help, once I get a rep of 15, I'll be sure to upvote.

Comment: Hey I noticed you asked another question relating to it, just looked at your code at testsite00.hostoi.com - you have to change  $("#gallery ul li") to add img, so it becomes $("#gallery ul li img").

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to set opacity to 0 prior to fading into 0.5 or whatever value.
If opacity is 1 and you tell it to fade to 0.5 it will go from 1 -> 0.5.